# Crash resistant screen recording

Tags: screen-recording

I have the following primary requirement for a screen recording tool: If the program or computer crashes or stops responding while recording, the recorded video until that point should not be lost. What programs/formats might fulfill this requirement?

Some additional criteria:

Compatible with Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Budget: Up to 200 EUR / USD.

Minimum frame rate: 15 FPS.

No specific requirement for file format, but *preferably* an open (non-proprietary) format.

Audio recording not required.

Screen resolution at least 1280 x 720.

Comment: Have you considered an external recorder, usually called a "game capture device" or similar? Some can interpose to your computer's hdmi output and record upto 1920x1080p at 60hz to an SDcard, independently of your computer. Eg, google for "AVerMedia Live Gamer Portable SDcard". See [this](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/17024) question on video.stackexchange.

Comment: The requirements are contradicting: the minimum FPS should be given at the maximum screen resolution, not the minimum.

Comment: While in principle, such a software might exist, did you consider that saving the video immediately (i.e. without cache) to disk results in high performance impact (especially on non-SSD)?